# 404 on static content (svg,woff,ttf) on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config

I am trying to add bootstrap `glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg` to my web site. Locally everything works fine, but on Azue I have 404 errors:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

or when I add below `staticContent` section to my web.config

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

I got this error:

> The controller for path
>   '/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' was not found or
>   does not implement IController.

How should I proper configure my ASP.NET site to avoid above errors?

Comment: How are you publishing to Azure? Is the file definitely there?

Comment: Using git. Moreover file in same folder (gif images) I can access without any problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not include font files in solution. This caused that publishing website does not contains this files.

Answer (score 79):

I hit the same problem with `.woff` file. Solution with adding that extension to `web.config` works fine:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

(see oryginal solution: http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/WOFF_files_return_404_in_Azure_Web_Sites)

Comment: needed to add this for serving up a JSON file too. Used:  `<mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />`

Comment: I had to add this with a `fileExtension=woff2`

Comment: Make sure this is done at the Root  "Web".config  Not in the Views --> web.config

Answer (score 20):

When I put the suggested lines into `web.config` it didn't work. Instead I put the following lines into `Web.config` (note the capital letter)

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" /> 
         </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the continuous deployment on Azure, verify that the "build action" of all the files that you need is Content and not None.

Comment: This fixed a similar problem I was having with LESS files, but I don't understand why.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed the paths in the css file that are referring to the font files? Bootstrap assumes that the css file is inside a css directory and fonts is inside a fonts-directory on the same level as the css-directory.

When you run in Azure, the site is probably running in Release-mode. This means that your css and javascript is minified and bundles. This may break your setup sometimes.

I've done the following setup when including bootstrap in my projects:

Unzip bootstrap files into the /Content directory.

Add the following lines to App_Start/BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap/css/bundle")
.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/bootstrap/js/bundle")
.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"));
```

Add the following lines to View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/css/bundle") 
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/js/bundle")
```

Note that jQuery must be included before the Bootstrap js-bundle.

http://hj-dev.blogspot.no/2013/02/add-twitter-bootstrap-to-mvc4.html