# ASP.NET MVC 5 on Azure: "The resource you are looking for has been removed..." for SVG files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, svg

I have created an MVC 5 web page with some views and controllers, added some images (gif and svg), and verified that it's mostly working locally. The images show up and everything behaves as expected.

When I deploy to Azure, the gif image loads fine, but the svg images give me the error `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` When I log into my website's FTP with my Azure credentials, the gif and svg files are all there. I can access my `/img/loading.gif` file from the web just fine; however, `/img/logo.svg` -- while it **does** exist in the directory and **does** show up when I run locally -- **is not** found when served by my Azure website.

I don't think it's relevant, but I am telling my website to route existing files:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

And all my images -- gif and svg -- are located in `Solution 'mySolutionName' -> myMvcProjectName -> img`. So there's nothing I can see that instructs my website to treat these files differently.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out this is a problem with `staticContent` MIME types, as in [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897079/404-on-static-content-svg-woff-ttf-on-azure).

To fix, I found my `<system.webServer>` section of my `Web.config`:

```
   <system.webServer>
     <modules>
       <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
     </modules>
   </system.webServer>
```

And added a `<staticContent>` mapping for SVG using its appropriate MIME type:

```
   <system.webServer>
     <modules>
       <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
     </modules>
     <staticContent>
       <mimeMap fileExtension="svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
     </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
```