# Glyphicons 404 Error on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, glyphicons

I am having a strange issue where glyphicons are not loading through a Mac.  I have tried Chrome v50 and Safari v9.  The icon is either not there, or a strange box.

[image]

But they load up fine on a PC

[image]

Here are the simple buttons I'm using:

```
<button title="Include" id="addToList" class="btn btn-default center-block add"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
<button title="Remove" class="btn btn-default center-block remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
```

The CSS:

```
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before { content: "\e080"; }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How is your glyph being declared in your css?

Comment: Ok, I added the CSS referring to the chevron glyph

Comment: If you copy the URL from your network tab, can you download the file directly on the mac?

Comment: It says, "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your answer is in this article:

[ASP.NET MVC 5 on Azure: "The resource you are looking for has been removed..." for SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516356/asp-net-mvc-5-on-azure-the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-f)

and here:

[404 on static content (svg,woff,ttf) on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897079/404-on-static-content-svg-woff-ttf-on-azure)